# (node: 5088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Dev validation failed: name: Path `name` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express'); const mongoose =
require('mongoose');

const routes = require('./routes');

const server = express();

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://izaac:izaac@cluster0-hzrrk.mongodb.net/omnistack8?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
{   useNewUrlParser: true });

server.use(express.json()); server.use(routes);

server.listen(3333);
```

**routes.js**

```
const express = require('express'); const DevController =
require('./controllers/DevController');

const routes = express.Router();

routes.post('/devs', DevController.store);

module.exports = routes;
```

**Dev.js**

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const DevSchema = new Schema({  name: {         type: String,       required:
true,   },      user: {         type: String,       required: true,         },  bio:
String,     avatar: {       type: String,       required: true,     }, }, {
timestamps: true, });

module.exports = model('Dev', DevSchema);
```

**DevController.js**

```
const axios = require('axios'); 
const Dev = require('../models/Dev');

module.exports = {  
  async store(req, res) {       
    const { username } = req.body;
        const userExists = await Dev.findOne({ user: username });

        if (userExists) {           
      return res.json(userExists);      
    }

        const response = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`);
        const { name, bio, avatar_url: avatar } = response.data;
        const dev = await Dev.create({          
       name,            
       user: username,          
       bio,
       avatar       
    });

     return res.json(dev);  
  } 
};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVVDS.png)

Comment: What is the `response` value? I guess it cause the mongoose validation error, when you pass the values towards mongoose.

Answer (score 1):

The 'name' field is required, but the response to your request has no 'name'.

Answer (score 0):

In your schema design, the key `name` is required, So you need to log what data will be pass in `Dev.create()`.